# Position Around a Point

Tags: javascript, math, vector-graphics

I have a central point on the page (x,y) and need to evenly distribute a varying number of items (div's) around that point in a circle.  The distance from the central point will be fixed.

This is my code thus far:

```
var noElements = $('div').size();
var xDistance = 100;
var angle = 0;
var offset = 250;

$('div').each(function(index) {
    angle = (360 / noElements)*index;

    $(this).css({'left': offset + (Math.sin(angle) * xDistance), 'top': offset + (Math.cos(angle) * xDistance)});
});​
```

This is code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUbAY/2/).

It's not quite working, if you add more div's in the fiddle you will see occasionally the div's are not evenly distributed. For example having 8 elements, causes two at the bottom to overlap.

Comment: Sorry just updated the fiddle.

Comment: how is it not working?  more description about what it is/isn't doing would be helpful.  how many elements? if you debug, what is angle starting out as?  i could see if you aren't using float math there, you'd end up with angle=0, and the rest of the math breaks down instantly?

Comment: @JohnGardner indeed the angle is starting at 0. I've edited the question with more details on how its not meeting my requirements. Math isn't my strong point, can you advise on float math?

Comment: Your `0.02` is the wrong setting for the number of elements you are trying to position in a circle.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how the 0.02 got in there. I've removed that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.sin` and `Math.cos` expect an angle in radians, not degress. You have to convert your angles to radians before passing:

```
var radians = degrees * (Math.PI/180);
```

Comment: @addedlovely isn't that what the `.02` is for? Just make it more precise .. `0.0175` should work

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your DIVs with

```
<div id="container" style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px">
...
</div>
```

(you forgot the #container element). But make sure you exclude it from `each()` (e.g. you can give all the other DIVs some CSS class and use it as `$("div.myclass")`).

Comment: oops, some things have changed

Answer (score 0):

You are using an approximation of PI = 3.6.

Change it to:

```
$('div').each(function(index) {
angle = ((3.1415926535897932384626433832795 * 2) / noElements)*index;

$(this).css({'left': offset + (Math.sin(angle) * xDistance), 
  'top': offset + (Math.cos(angle) * xDistance)});
  });
```

Would look more round if the divs were circles :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not writing out a full example but I don't have a lot of time at the moment.

At the top of your source, you'll need these:

```
var radToDeg = Math.PI / 180;
var incrementingAngle = 360 / noElements;
var currentAngle = 0;
```

And in your foreach loop's css settings...

```
left: Math.sin(currentAngle * radToDeg),
top: Math.cos(currentAngle * radToDeg)
```

And at the end of each loop:

```
currentAngle += incrementingAngle;
```